# Updating a field in MondoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing a multi-user online dictionary. I want to implement a leadership board, e.i. "score" attribute increases, as soon as a user adds a word. I have a rough idea on how to do it, and tried one solution, however it does not work. Could you please guide me?

**Word API route**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Word = require('../../models/Word');
const User = require('../../models/User');

const validateWordInput = require('../../validation/word');
const passport = require('passport');

// @route  POST api/words
// @desc   Add words to profile
// @access Private
router.post(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Word.find({}).then(word => {
      if (
        word.filter(
          wrd =>
            wrd.ugrWordCyr.toString().toLowerCase() ===
            req.body.ugrWordCyr.toLowerCase()
        ).length !== 0
      ) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ wordalreadyexists: 'Word already exists' });
      } else {
        const newWord = new Word({
          user: req.user.id,
          ugrWordCyr: req.body.ugrWordCyr,
          rusTranslation: req.body.rusTranslation,
          example: req.body.example,
          exampleTranslation: req.body.exampleTranslation,
          origin: req.body.origin,
          sphere: req.body.sphere,
          lexis: req.body.lexis,
          grammar: req.body.grammar,
          partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
          style: req.body.style
        });

        newWord.save().then(word => res.json(word));
        User.update(
          { _id: '5cf0cb78b3105d1ba8e30331' },
          { $inc: { score: 1 } }
        );
      }
    });
  }
);
```

**User model**

*This is where a score attribute is located*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  score: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Comment: what is the first thing you would like to accomplish with this feature?

Comment: I want my score field updates, when a new word is added through a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successfully saving the word, we should update the user count

To update the respective user's score you can do the following:

```
newWord.save().then((word) => {

    //now update user model
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }) <-- or an id you would like
        .then((foundUser) => {
             foundUser.score = foundUser.score + 1

             foundUser.save()
                .then((savedUser) => {
                    res.json({ word, savedUser })
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return res.status(400).json({ error: "could not add score"})
                })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           return res.status(400).json({ error: "could not find user"})
        })

})
```

Comment: You will get an error about sending multiple responses since you are trying to send one after the word save and after the user update. Also i was wondering is it a good practice to send a response to the client before db operations complete successfully ?

Comment: @AsafAviv thats interesting, I wonder if its better to just send one response as an array that includes all responses. OP would probably have to update his promise-handlers on the front-end to consume them.

Comment: Its impossible to get the second response though  because `res.json` calls `res.end`

Comment: @AsafAviv, right, so maybe we could remove the first res.json() and then pass in the word response in an obj with the savedUser

Comment: No need for an array we can send it as json after we update the score as `res.json({ word, savedUser });`

Comment: @AsafAviv thanks, I didnt realize that after reading it again myself haha. :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo, I tried your code, unfortunately I can't make it work.

Comment: @NZMAI the value probably isnt displaying the way you want on the frontend, are u getting any errors when hitting this route?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo, could I ask you, where the "score" value is stored? In your implementation?

Comment: @NZMAI the score value should be coming from the User model. Since we are able to find the User using User.findOne(), we can tap into the returned data, which we call foundUser. foundUser would have a property called score. And we just update the score as intended. The problem you might be experiencing is that you might have added score as a new property inside your model, but the existing users do not have that property yet. So when you try to update it, theres no value to update.

Comment: Ok, but when I add a word, the score is not updated. I looked at the console.log. when a word is added, the console logs POST http://localhost:3000/api/words 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194234/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-nzmai).